# Как вывести из БД sqlite3 строку (в которой есть html теги), так, чтобы эти теги читались?

Tags: django, sqlite, sqlite3

Как вывести из БД sqlite3 строку (в которой есть html теги), так, чтобы эти теги читались?
Например строка "< p >Тут самый обычный текст< / p>" , выводилась бы как `<p>Тут самый обычный текст</p>` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ответом является использование es[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-escape)cape